# Control Flow Graph for C++ - static analyzer

Tags: c++, code-analysis

I've created code coverage tool for C++. As output, this tool returns xml file with numbers of all executed lines in source files.

Now, I would like to visualize analyzed source files as graphs, where single node is related to single code line, and edge shows control flow. Nodes of executed lines would be highlighted with green, and not executed - grayed out (for instance).

**All I need** is software or library which would analyze source files and generate some representation of control flow graph (event not exactly graph as image, but it might be also graph representation in file).

Do you know any free software or library to achieve that?

I'm working under Windows and Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: Do you have an example on what you want to achieve. Maybe like the graphs in IDA Pro?

Comment: Let's say I've got source file (.cpp). I built this file and ran my tool to get code coverage data for this file. Then I run some static analyzer to generate Control Flow Graph of this source file, and it returns me some data that I could use to generate such image in i.e. GraphViz: http://scitools.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/graph_views_control_flow_c.png

Comment: I know of one that is not free, that handles MS Windows C++ source code extremely well.